# How to find value of previous cell for conditional formation in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to figure out a way to make it so that if the cell in the previous column is less than the cell then the cell will become highlighted green using conditional formatting.

For example if B1 is "100" and A1 is "50" then conditional formation will automatically make B1 highlighted green

I've tried doing

format cells if...
Greater than

```
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1))
```

but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution;
If you do

Format cells if... Custom formula is

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))>INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1))
```

Then it will work for any range which you input

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXlrh.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional formatting in in like the following highlight (B2:B) range

1. Select the cell (B1) that you want to apply conditional formatting to.
2. Click on "Format" in the top menu.
3. Choose "Conditional formatting" from the dropdown menu.
4. In the "Conditional format rules" pane that appears on the right, set up the rule as follows:

   - Format cells if: "Custom formula is"
   - Enter the following formula:

```
=B2>A1
```

[image]

whenever the value in cell B1 is greater than the value in cell A1, cell B1 will be highlighted in green.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Sorry I should have gave for information, I want to be able to have a large range of cell all under one conditional format. So for example I want B1:D10 to turn green if it is greater than the cell to the left of it just from one conditional format.